# Does VsCode automatically update the .Net SDK version?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-code

Having a frustrating issue with something on my windows 10 PC updating my DotNet SDK version from 6.0.102 to 6.0.103.  This is a problem as one of the software projects I work on is the hard locked to certain SDK versions.

Does visual studio code automatically update this or is it something else?  Either way it would be good to know a way to turn it off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visual Studio Code does not update .NET SDK version in your system, since it is a pure code editor with extension support and does not mess up with other components and applications in the computer.

However, these can update your .NET SDK version:

- **Updating Visual Studio:** Unlike VSCode, Visual Studio manages other components in the computer and may update .NET SDK version as you update Visual Studio.
- **Microsoft Update:** .NET Runtime and SDK installations may be updated automatically via Microsoft Update if you use Windows and this switch is *On* in your Windows Update Advanced Settings:

[image: Windows Update Advanced Settings]

#### Fixing SDK Version

There is a way to fix which SDK version is used by the compiler by adding a global.json file on the project or solution directory with the correct SDK version:

```
{
  "sdk": {
    "version": "6.0.102"
  }
}
```

If you add the file in the root directory, the file will be taken into consideration for all projects in that directory and also in sub-directories. With this method, you can still use older SDK versions if they exists in your system.

For more info: [Select the .NET version to use](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/versions/selection)

#### .NET SDK Versioning

.NET SDK uses a special versioning. According to that, there should be no difference between version 6.0.102 and 6.0.103 other than bugfixes. Therefore, it would be a nice idea to reconsider the SDK version coupling even in patch versions such as the example versions you provided.

For more info: [Overview of how .NET is versioned](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/versions/)